# PHP cookie won't set in all directories unless expiration time is defined

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to get this cookie to act as a session but it won't set unless I provide it with an expiration date. The cookie will work if I add an expiration. Is there something that I can add to the cookie to make it act as a session?

```
setcookie("dash", $row['Unique_ID'], '/');
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `setcookie()` is the expiration date of the cookie represented as a Unix timestamp. The path of the cookie is the fourth parameter. You cannot just omit the third parameter if you wish to set the path only. But you can set it to zero if you want it to expire when the browser clsoes.

```
setcookie("dash", $row['Unique_ID'], 0, '/');
```

Comment: So setting the expiration to `0` will make the cookie expire on browser close?

Comment: Yes. From the manual: `If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).`